# How to i get Google Advertising ID using Php l/ JavaScript ike Appsflyer

Tags: javascript, php, appsflyer

Appsflyer can Retrieve Google Advertising Id in Web. But How can i Get Google Advertising ID by using php or Js. Any Library or any thing that can help me to get gaid. I searched almost every question but they are for apps [ java ... ]. I want to fetch it by the php or JavaScript.

As Per this -> [AppsFlyer GAID](https://www.appsflyer.com/glossary/gaid/)

Comment: Asking for suggestions/recommendations about libraries are [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There's a reason why most results are in Java. As it says on the page you linked to: _"Google Advertising ID — aka GAID, aka Android ID, aka Android Advertising ID (AAID) — is a **device** unique identifier that enables **app** developers..."_.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I am not asking about any suggestions i am asking is there any library which i can use for this task

Comment: _"Any Library or any thing that can help me to get gaid"_ is literally asking us for suggestions about libraries, because I seriously doubt you would be satisfied with only a "yes" to that question without getting the name of it.